# Mathematic modelisation of a gym members

Tags: mathematical-modeling

i'm working on a business case, where i should run a gym (gym club/fitness club). 
I want to know if there's some well know mathematic modelisations ready made for that kind of cases. 
For instance, let's say i have 100 members, is there a formula to estimate the mean members that would come everyday ? (like a gaussian?)
The good thing would be to estimate the mean of members coming everyday with extremes : standard deviation?

I know it could be a silly question but that would be very important to me

Thanks for your feedbacks

Hervé from France

Comment: Note : i'm a business guy, not a mathematician, please be kind with your inputs and formulas ! ;))